# Using posttext to systematically check list of numbers via website

Tags: android, app-inventor

Have enabled a function in my app which checks up to 12 serial numbers programatically from an android app built in app inventor. 
Recently there has been a change in the website code, which has broken the function.

I am trying to analyse the actions that occur when the 'send' button is clicked on the web site.

Am using wireshark. Have managed to 'see' what occurs when button is pressed.

It appears the _VIEWSTATE variable has changed.

Does anyone know if that would break the app?

web site I am querying http://vppneuapps.volvo.com/ww/PIE/PIE.aspx?lang=en-GB

app I have built http://goo.gl/xZCPO (free download)

Any advice/ help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Tribble, could you provide an example query (serial number, engine type, etc.)? `Does anyone know if that would break the app?` probably yes...

Comment: Hi Taifun. Thought you might be around here somewhere! lol.  I am querying serial number 2003004555. Try that in the web site.

Comment: probably Scott's example can help https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/app-inventor-developers-library/asp/app-inventor-developers-library/jsNombfo9S0/O4KqKw0kVQsJ

Comment: Thanks for that pointer Taifun. I have gone back over my code and found an error. It was not parsing VIEWSTATE value from response code properly. Will be reviewing and re-testing tonight. fingers crossed!! will post result here and in groups when done.

Answer (score 1):

Question answered by myself.

Zip file for app inventor [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/programming-with-app-inventor/p3GUtPJFvN0)